# iOS, How to copy a object without changing its pointer?

Tags: ios

In objective-c, NSCopying protocol provide us `copy` and `mutableCopy`. They all implement the `copyWithZone:` selector. Now, my requirement is:

For A : address is `0x00002bfa`

```
A.name = @"John";
A.age = 10;
```

For B : address is `0x0000843d`

```
B.name = @"Lily";
B.age = 20;
```

After `A = [B customCopy];`

Now A is:

For A : address is `0x00002bfa`

```
A.name = @"Lily";
A.age = 20;
```

Only change the value of properties of A, the address still no change.
Cause it is custom NSObject. I think NSCopying could not work. Cause `copy` and `mutableCopy` will change the pointer of A, let it point to B. It is not my will.

Is it clear? Any idea! I am confused by the problem a long time. Thank you!

Comment: NSCopying only change the values not the address. And i think you want that the address of object A also changed when values are changed?

Comment: Please clarify your question. If you want to change the address of A then why do you copy and assign? Just create a new instance and initialize it with properties of B.

Comment: Thanks AniKhechoyan and warisshams, I do not want the change the address of A. I want A keep it's old pointer.. NSCopying can not do this, I strongly believe! In my example, I show you the address of A is `0x00002bfa` from the begin to the end!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sergii's solution should work, but if you want to wander to uncharted teritories you could try something like:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
...
memcpy((__bridge void *)A, (__bridge const void *)B, class_getInstanceSize([A class]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
- (void) assignPropertiesFrom:(Object *) object {
    self.name = object.name;
    self.age  = self.age;
}

[A assignPropertiesFrom:B];
```

It will repopulate A with property values of B, but A will still be the same object, so anyone holding pointers to it will have all the changes